# AI character doesn't walk on the floor

Tags: unity, c#, terrain

When I execute my game, I have this script that makes the tiger follow me, but he doesn't detect the terrain under him and ends up floating in the air.

[image: The tiger floating in the air.]

---

These are the components, on the tiger.

[image: Tiger components: Rigidbody (Mass: 1; Drag: 0; Angular Drag: 0.05; Use Gravity: True; Is Kinematic: True; Interpolate: None; Collision Detection: Discrete), Mesh Collider(Convex: False; Material: ZeroFriction; Mesh: Tiger_Mesh), Script (Script: TigerChase; Player: FPSController)]

This is the script `TigerChase`.

```
public class TigerChase : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform player;
    static Animator anim;

    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update () 
    {   
        if (Vector3.Distance (player.position, this.transform.position) < 20) 
        {
            Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
            direction.y = 0;
            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp 
                    (this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (direction), 0.1f);
            anim.SetBool ("IsIdle", false);

            if (direction.magnitude > 5) 
            {
                this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.20f);
                anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("IsAtacking", false);
            } 
            else 
            {
                anim.SetBool ("IsAtacking", true);
                anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", false);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            anim.SetBool ("IsIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", true);
            anim.SetBool ("IsAtacking", true);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the zero friction material in the mesh collider?

Answer (score 1):

You have IsKinematic set to true on the Rigidbody. This is telling the physics engine, among other things, that you will apply gravity yourself. Your script does no such thing, so you either need to manually apply gravitational movement, or disable IsKinematic and use the built-in physics engine.